# CSS Positioning over a YouTube Video

Tags: css, properties, css-position

Good day
Please I Need help

I have this css that I have created for preventing someone from clicking the right part of the youtube video I have embeded

The challenge is that I need to create another div that has the same box but want it to be on the same line to the top left of the video

What I have is below.
How can I create another div but that would not be under?

```
<div style="width: 150px; height: 545px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; right: 1px; top: 2px; background-color: #000000;"></div>

<div style="width: 150px; height: 545px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; right: 1px; top: 2px; background-color: #000000;"></div>
```

I want the box to be on the same line
One to the top left line one to the top right on the same line

Comment: A [example] would be helpful.

Comment: Is something like this what you're trying to accomplish? https://jsfiddle.net/dm2of1ae/ If so, I can write out an explanation as an answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Surprisingly after going through some trainings on W3 Schools
I came up with this and it solved the problem.

```
<div style="width: 150px; height: 545px; position: absolute; z-index: 1; opacity: 0.01; right: 1px; top: 2px; background-color: #000000;"></div>


<div style="width: 350px; height: 70px;  position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; left: 1px; top: 2px; background-color: #000000;"></div>

<div style="width: 190px; height: 50px;  position: absolute; opacity: 0.01; left: 0px; bottom: 190px; background-color: #000000;"></div>
```